# Is it possible to use Android libraries in visual studio 2012 MVC 4

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if it is possible to import the android library to a visual studio 2012 mvc 4 application?

I have created a web application application in c# and it did say that I could import the android libraries but I just can't figure out how.

I have been trying everything and haven't found any solutions.

Is there possibly an extension that I would need to install?

Sorry I know this seems like a broad question, but I am just trying to not re-code my entire application in another language.

Thanks for your time.

Rene

Comment: As Marco asks below, why would you want to import Android libraries into a web application?

Comment: Also, the basic control flow of Android vs MVC is very different, as one is statefull and the other is stateless. You should maybe read up on the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, because native Android libraries are java based, what you can do though is use third party libraries such as: http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid that allow you to build Android apps with C#, which then convert your code to android binaries.

One thing I don't understand is why you would want to use Android libraries in a Web Application.